# Shortcode error

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, shortcode

I've created a plugin that includes the shortcode below, it works fine one website ( http://www.porministries.org/wordpress/?page_id=16 ) but not on another website ( http://www.rccov.com/media/ ). I get the following error code

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 345

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_sermon_info' );

function create_sermon_info() {
    register_post_type( 'sermon',
        array(
          'labels' => array(
         'name'                => _x( 'Sermons', 'Post Type General Name', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Sermon', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Sermon', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Sermon:', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Sermons', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Sermons', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Sermon', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New Sermon', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Sermon', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Sermon', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search sermons', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No sermons found', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No sermons found in Trash', 'marvilmedia' ),
            ),


        'label'               => __( 'sermons', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'description'         => __( 'every sunday sermon audio', 'marvilmedia' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ), //  'thumbnail',
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'series', 'preacher' ),
          'query_var'          => true,
          'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'Sermon' ),
          'hierarchical'        => false,
          'public'              => true,
          'show_ui'             => true,
          'show_in_menu'        => true,
          'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
          'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
          'menu_position' => null,
          'menu_icon' => '',
          'menu_position' => 5,
          'can_export'          => true,
          'has_archive'         => true,
          'exclude_from_search' => false,
          'publicly_queryable'  => true,
          'capability_type'     =>  'post'

        )
    );
}



/**
 * Add preacher taxonomies
 *
 * Additional preacher taxonomies can be defined here
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
 */
add_action( 'init', 'add_sermon_taxonomies', 0 );

function add_sermon_taxonomies() {
    // Add new "Preachers" taxonomy to Posts
    register_taxonomy('preacher', array( 'sermon' ), array(
        // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
        'hierarchical' => false,
        // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Preachers', 'taxonomy general name', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Preacher', 'taxonomy singular name', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Preachers', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Preachers', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Preacher', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Preacher:', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Preacher', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Preacher', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Preacher', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Preacher Name', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Preachers', 'marvilmedia'  ),
        ),
                     'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,// Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'preachers', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/preachers/"
            'hierarchical' => false // This will allow URL's like "/preachers/boston/cambridge/"
        ),
    ));


/**
 * Add series series
 *
 * Additional series series can be defined here
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
 */
    // Add new "Series" taxonomy to Posts
    register_taxonomy('series', 'sermon', array(
        // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
        'hierarchical' => false,
        // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Series', 'taxonomy general name', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Series', 'taxonomy singular name', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Series', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Series', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Series', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Series:', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Series', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Series', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Series', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Series Name', 'marvilmedia'  ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Series', 'marvilmedia'  ),
        ),
                     'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,// Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'series', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/series/"
            'hierarchical' => false // This will allow URL's like "/series/boston/cambridge/"
        ),
    ));
}



function include_sermon_single_template( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'sermon' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-sermon.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/single-sermon.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_sermon_single_template', 1 );



function include_sermon_series_taxonomy_template( $template_path ) {
     if ( get_post_type() == 'sermon' ) {

   // is a specific custom taxonomy being shown?
        if ( is_tax('series') ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'taxonomy-series.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/taxonomy-series.php';

            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;

}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_sermon_series_taxonomy_template', 1 );

function include_sermon_preacher_taxonomy_template( $template_path ) {
     if ( get_post_type() == 'sermon' ) {

   // is a specific custom taxonomy being shown?
        if ( is_tax('preacher') ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'taxonomy-preacher.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/taxonomy-preacher.php';

            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;

}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_sermon_preacher_taxonomy_template', 1 );



//add extra fields to custom taxonomy edit form callback function
function extra_tax_fields($tag) {
   //check for existing taxonomy meta for term ID
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id");
?>
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Category Image Url'); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="term_meta[img]" id="term_meta[img]" size="3" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['img'] ? $term_meta['img'] : ''; ?>"><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Image for Term: use full url with '); ?></span>
        </td>
</tr>
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra1"><?php _e('Series Date'); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="term_meta[extra1]" id="term_meta[extra1]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['extra1'] ? $term_meta['extra1'] : ''; ?>"><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('The date of the series'); ?></span>
        </td>
</tr>
<?php
}

// save extra taxonomy fields callback function
function save_extra_taxonomy_fields( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['term_meta']);
            foreach ($cat_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['term_meta'][$key])){
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        //save the option array
        update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
    }
}

// this adds the fields
add_action('series_add_form_fields','extra_tax_fields', 10, 2 ); 
// this saves the fields
add_action('created_series','save_extra_taxonomy_fields', 10, 2);

add_action( 'series_edit_form_fields', 'extra_tax_fields', 10, 2);
add_action( 'edited_series', 'save_extra_taxonomy_fields', 10, 2);

// this adds the fields
add_action('preacher_add_form_fields','extra_tax_fields', 10, 2 ); 
// this saves the fields
add_action('created_preacher','save_extra_taxonomy_fields', 10, 2);
add_action( 'preacher_edit_form_fields', 'extra_tax_fields', 10, 2);
add_action( 'edited_preacher', 'save_extra_taxonomy_fields', 10, 2);



/* ----- Embed the Event Listings Shortcode ----- */

// Register a new shortcode: [sermon] 

function section_sermon_shortcode( $atts ) {
    //ob_start();
extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => -1, 'preacher' => '', 'series' => ''), $atts, $content = null ) );

$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  

query_posts(  array ( 
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
    'post_type' => 'sermon', 
    'post_status'  =>  'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC',        
    'preacher' => $preacher,
    'series' => $series,
    //'category_name' => $category,
    'paged' => $paged ) );


$list = ' ';   
$counter =0;
while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
 ++$counter;
  if($counter == 3) {
    $postclass = 'class="last"';
    $counter = 0;
  } else { $postclass = ''; }

    $list .= '<li '.$postclass.'>' 
    //. '<div class="listing-content">' 
   // . '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>' 
   // .'<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>'
   // . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . 'View &raquo;' . '</a>'
   // . '</div>'
    . '<a class="listing-thumb" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full')  . '</a>'
    . '</li>';
}
   //$list = ob_get_clean();
return 
'<ul class="sermon-listing clear">' 
. $list 
. '<div class="nav-previous">' . get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ) ) . '</div>'
. '<div class="nav-next">' . get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) . '</div>'
. '</ul>' .
wp_reset_query();

}
add_shortcode( 'sermon', 'section_sermon_shortcode' );
// the shortcode -> [sermon] or [sermon limit="5" preacher="john smith" series="holy flame"]





// Register a new shortcode: [sermon series] 

function section_sermon_series_shortcode( $atts ) {
    //ob_start();
extract( shortcode_atts( $atts, $content = null ) );

$args = array('hide_empty' => 1,'orderby' => 'none',  'order' => 'ASC', );

$terms = get_terms( 'series', $args );


if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $counter = count( $terms );

$counter =0;

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
       ++$counter;
  if($counter == 4) {
    $postclass = 'class="last"';
    $counter = 0;
  } else { $postclass = ''; }

 $t_ID = $term->term_id; //id-ul taxonomiei
$term_data = get_option("taxonomy_$t_ID");
// if (isset($term_data['img'])){ $term_list = $term_data['img']; } 

        $term_list .= '<li '.$postclass.'><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '"><img src="' . $term_data['img'] . '" alt="'. $term->name . '"></a></li>';

      endforeach;

}

return 
'<ul class="sermon-listing clear">' 
. $term_list
. '<div class="nav-previous">' . get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ) ) . '</div>'
. '<div class="nav-next">' . get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) . '</div>'
. '</ul>' .
wp_reset_query();

}
add_shortcode( 'sermon-series', 'section_sermon_series_shortcode' );
// the shortcode -> [sermon-series]






function sermon_script_footer(){ 

wp_register_style('sermon-style',plugins_url( '/css/sermon-style.css' , __FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_style('sermon-style');
 } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'sermon_script_footer'); 

/* ----- Embed the Event Listings Widget ----- */


class SermonsByMarvilMedia extends WP_Widget
{

function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'SermonsByMarvilMedia', 'description' => __('Displays sermons by marvil media', 'SermonsByMarvilMedia'));
    //$control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 300);
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Sermons By Marvil Media', 'SermonsByMarvilMedia'), $widget_ops ); //$control_ops );
}  

  function form($instance)
  {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $numberOfSermons = esc_attr($instance['numberOfSermons']);

?>
  <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title', 'SermonsByMarvilMedia'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('numberOfSermons'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Sermons:', 'SermonsByMarvilMedia'); ?></label>       
        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('numberOfSermons'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('numberOfSermons'); ?>">
            <?php for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++): ?>
            <option <?php echo $x == $numberOfSermons ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x; ?></option>
            <?php endfor;?>
        </select>
        </p>         
<?php
  }

  function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
  {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['numberOfSermons'] = strip_tags($new_instance['numberOfSermons']);

    return $instance;
  }

  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo $before_widget;
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
     $numberOfSermons = $instance['numberOfSermons'];

    if (!empty($title))
      echo '<i class="fa fa-headphones"><span>' . $title . '</span></i>';


    // WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
    global $post;
        //  add_image_size( 'SermonsByMarvilMedia_size', 85, 45, false );
        $listings = new WP_Query();
        $listings->query('post_type=sermon&posts_per_page=' . $numberOfSermons );   
        if($listings->found_posts > 0) {
            //echo '<ul class="SermonsByMarvilMedia">';
                while ($listings->have_posts()) {
                    $listings->the_post();
                    $listItem .=  the_post_thumbnail('full');
                    //$listItem .= '<div class="homepage-player">';
                    $listItem .= the_content();
                    //$listItem .='</div>';
                    $listItem .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">'.get_the_title() . '</a>';
                    //$listItem .= '<span>Added ' . get_the_date() . '</span></li>'; 
                    echo $listItem; 

                }
            //echo '</ul>';
            wp_reset_postdata(); 
        }else{
            echo '<p style="padding:25px;">No sermon found</p>';
        } 

    echo $after_widget;
  }

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("SermonsByMarvilMedia");') );
```

Comment: What's in `$terms`? Can you post the results of `print_r( $terms );` right before your foreach loop in a comment?

Comment: @redelschaap let me try and let you know in a minute

Comment: @redelschaap this is the result Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 9 [name] => The Good Life [slug] => the-good-life [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 9 [taxonomy] => series [description] => "

Comment: There are more info but I couldn't post it all, I was over in characters allow to post

Comment: Here is the link to the page result http://www.rccov.com/media/

Comment: I can't see why it would give that foreach error with this code. The only foreach loop that could give an error is `foreach ($cat_keys as $key){` in case `$_POST['term_meta']` is not an array, but I don't think that's your line 345. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @redelschaap when i check the codes in line 345 this what i see function shortcode_atts( $pairs, $atts, $shortcode = '' ) {
 $atts = (array)$atts;
 $out = array();
 foreach($pairs as $name => $default) {
  if ( array_key_exists($name, $atts) )
   $out[$name] = $atts[$name];
  else
   $out[$name] = $default;
 }

Comment: Ah, that's why I couldn't find your error. If that is line 345, then $pairs is not an array when you call `shortcode_atts()`. My guess is that it would be on the `extract( shortcode_atts( $atts, $content = null ) );` line in your `section_sermon_series_shortcode()` function. It seems that you forgot the first parameter there.

Comment: Also note that `extract( shortcode_atts( $atts, null ) );` is the same as `extract( shortcode_atts( $atts, $content = null ) );` in your case.

Comment: @redelschaap its fix, thank you so much, i removed extract( shortcode_atts( $atts, $content = null ) ); and voila everything is working perfectly fine now